# Lost connection

Tags: ios, file, upload

I'm trying to make photo upload in my apps. When photo size is bigger than 10 Mb app crashed, xcode shows me "Connection to assetsd was interrupted or assetsd died" and also shows message "Lost connection to Maria's iPhone".
How to fix this?

Comment: Append your code please. Check your server side settings.

Comment: are you using AFNetwork or NSURLSession for uploading image

Comment: NSURLSession. What server settings could cause "lost connection" error? Looks more like Xcode problems for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in app. It used too much memory. 
When I restart iPhone, I can upload that photo and see this: [image]

So I will seek problems with memory in my app, not on server or in xcode itself.

Comment: Hey Maria, Did you find out any solution for this issue?